# NoSuchMethod exception when requesting file using Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm using Ktor Client 1.6.5 to ask for files to an API. Every time I tried to GET the resource, I get this exception:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;`

It seems to be related to this [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3244).

I'm changing a lot the code (mostly the get response) but mainly it is like that:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO)
val response = client.get<HttpResponse>("url") {
    headers {
        append(HttpHeaders.Accept, "application/zip")
    }
}
```

Basically I can't even handle the response (or its content).

EDIT: the files exposed by the API are not large (usually less than 1Mb)

Comment: This is a bug in Ktor 1.6.5 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3358) that will be fixed in the next upcoming release. As a workaround, please use JDK 11 or later.

Comment: Thanks @AlekseiTirman! Since I can't change to JDK 11, I read the issue and downgraded Ktor to 1.6.4 and works fine!